# How to derive A in this expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

How can I derive A in this matrix represented equation(a closed form solution for ridge regression) $$\ a= (X^T X + αI)^
{−1} X^T y  $$ (-1 here is inverse) and  $a = X^TA$  I have to get
$$\ α^{-1}(y-Xa) .$$
But I am not sure how can i get to it .
TIA!

Comment: Is that supposed to be an inverse symbol, a {-1} exponent?

Comment: yes, edited, thanks- it is inverse

Comment: Is "a" a matrix?  It looks as if that is how you are using it; I'm just used to seeing uppercase letters for matrices and lowercase for scalars.

Comment: it is vector here

Comment: Also did not say what $X, \alpha, y$ are.

Comment: X is nx1 matrix,  is const, and y is vector

Comment: If $X$ is $n \times 1$, a column vector, then $X^T$ is $1 \times n$, a row vector, and $X^TX$ is a scalar.  And $\alpha$ you say is a scalar.  So doesn't that make $I$ a scalar as well?  Please edit your question itself to show what are what sizes.

Comment: edited, but i think it should not  matter

Comment: So, is $A$ an $n\times n$ matrix, as well as $I$?  And doesn't that make $a$ a row vector?  I'm sorry but I don't see how your matrices are even conformable here.

Comment: And what is that asterisk supposed to represent, multiplication?  And if so, of what?

Comment: idk about A, but asterisk is just multiplication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122893/discussion-between-robertthetutor-and-jack-vorobey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\ X^TX+αI$ and its inverse are scalars. This is because $X$ is an $n \times 1$ matrix, so $X^T$ is $1 \times n$ and thus $X^TX$ is $1 \times 1$. Thus, we can move this around without worring about its order, unlike matrices.

Use the hint as the first step (after substituting the expression for $a$):
\begin{align}
\ a&= (X^T X + \alpha I)^
{−1} X^T y \\
X^TA &= (X^T X + \alpha I)^
{−1} X^T y \\
(X^T X + \alpha I)X^TA &= X^T y \\
(\alpha^{-1}X^T X + I)X^TA &= \alpha^{-1}X^T y \\
\alpha^{-1}X^T X X^T A + X^T A&= \alpha^{-1}X^T y \\
X^T A&= \alpha^{-1}X^T y - \alpha^{-1}X^T X X^T A \\
(X^T)^{-1}X^T A&= \alpha^{-1}(X^T)^{-1}X^T y - \alpha^{-1}(X^T)^{-1}X^T X X^T A \\
A&= \alpha^{-1} y - \alpha^{-1} X X^T A \\
A&= \alpha^{-1} (y -  X X^T A) \\
A&= \alpha^{-1} (y -  X a).
\end{align}
Of course, this is only valid if

- $X^T X + \alpha I \neq 0$, and
- $X^T$ is invertible, which happens if and only if $X$ is invertible i.e. non-singular.

Comment: You said X is a vector.  How can it be invertible?